# Validation of the form (three first characters different from the space)

Tags: regex, html, forms

I do not know how to enter the validation in the folmula. I want the first 3 characters to be different from the space (sign = " ").

**Example:**

Surname is: "(space before the surname)xyz"- error.

Surname is "aaa aaaaa" - correct.

Surname is"aa aaaaaa" - error.

Surname is "(no space before the name)XYZ" - correctly

My code with which I tried:

```html
<input type="text" name="surname" class="input-medium flat has- 
    placeholder" required="required" id="surname" data-validation- 
    rule="minLength" data-validation-value="2" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,25}+[" "]+ 
    [A-Za-z]" aria-required="true" placeholder="surname">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex pattern to match what you are after:

```
^[A-Za-z]+$|[A-Za-z]{3,25}\s[A-Za-z]+
```

Here:

- `^[A-Za-z]+$` means a string starting with and ending with one or of more characters 'A' to 'Z' (uppercase) and 'a' to 'z' (lowercase)
- `|` - means OR select the following:
- `[A-Za-z]{3,25}` - means characters 'A' to 'Z' (uppercase) and 'a' to 'z' (lowercase) of length between 3 and 25.
- `\s` - means a whitespace character
- `[A-Za-z]+` - means characters 'A' to 'Z' (uppercase) and 'a' to 'z' (lowercase) of one or more in length.

See working example below:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="surname" class="input-medium flat has- 
placeholder" required="required" id="surname" data-validation- 
rule="minLength" data-validation-value="2" pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$|[A-Za-z]{3,25}\s[A-Za-z]+" aria-required="true" placeholder="surname">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Please note:** Using the `pattern` attribute isn't a valid form of input validation. This can always be changed and bypassed by the end user using *inspect* tools.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Problem with when one wants to get one segment name.

Comment: @JohnBath Hm? What do you mean by "one segment name" ?

Comment: The problem is as follows:
surname = "XYZ (space) XXX" - correct
surname = "XYZZZ" - correct
surname = "space, space XYZ" - error
The point is that the person in the forms could not enter the spaces themselves. Sometimes, the name is Van Bath and sometimes only Bath. I want to avoid a situation when someone types only spaces.Maybe it can be done without using "pattern"?

Comment: Here you say `surname="XYZZZ" is `correct` but above in your question, you say `surname = "xyz"` is an `error`. That is why my answer gives `error` if you only put one name. I can update my answer to check that the field isn't only spaces

Comment: You're right. There is a mistake in the question - it's not your fault. I am correcting already. Thank you for active help.

Comment: @JohnBath ok, I've looked at your updated question and amended my answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @JohnBath no worries. Don't forget to mark this answer as answered if it answers your question